# SharePoint DateTimeControl does not render the calendar in web part

Tags: web-part, visual-web-part, visual-studio-2013, datetimecontrol

I have created a web part for creating new list item using VS.

Web part has a DateTime Control.

If I click on Calendar icon then it does not render it, rather gives a server error.

[image]

I have included TagPrefix as follows-

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

and control is placed as

```
<SharePoint:DateTimeControl ID="dtcStartDate" runat="server"  DateOnly="True" Calendar="ChineseLunar" />
```

Kindly help me resolve this problem.

Comment: Can you copy the full error message.

Comment: You should consider relative or absolute path when you put DatePickerFrameUrl !

Answer (score 1):

Beware that `$SPUrl` is token known only in SharePoint Server editions and it is not available in SharePoint Foundation. Using `$SPUrl` in SharePoint Foundations throws an exception `The expression prefix 'SPUrl' was not recognized`

SharePoint Server:

```
<SharePoint:DateTimeControl runat="server" ID="date" DatePickerFrameUrl="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/_layouts/15/iframe.aspx %>" />
```

SharePoint Foundation:

```
<SharePoint:DateTimeControl runat="server" ID="date" DatePickerFrameUrl='<%# SPContext.Current.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/_layouts/15/iframe.aspx" %>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

As SharePoint:DateTimeControl Crashes in SP2013 Webpart.
Try below:

```
<SharePoint:DateTimeControl ID="dtStartdate" runat="server" DateOnly="true" DatePickerFrameUrl="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/_layouts/15/iframe.aspx %>" />
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<SharePoint:DateTimeControl ID="dtControl" runat="server" DateOnly="true" DatePickerFrameUrl="../_layouts/15/iframe.aspx" />
```